# How to send nested json data and image together in one HTTP POST request in Android?

Tags: java, android, json, http

I'm currently using `org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder`. The following don't work:

`.addPart("key", new StringBody(jsonObject.toString()))`

`.addTextBody("key", jsonObject.toString())`

`.addTextBody("key", jsonObject.toString(), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)`

Here, `jsonObject` is an `org.json.JSONObject`.

Non-nested fields and the image field validates correctly, but the nested fields don't seem to get filled out (the server returns "This field is required.").

Solutions that don't use the `MultipartEntityBuilder` are welcome as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multipart data does not play well with nested json. I settled for flattening the nested fields in the server API. Then, building the request still using `MultipartEntityBuilder`:

```
HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
.addTextBody("inner_key1", jsonObject.get("inner_key1").toString())
.addTextBody("inner_key2", jsonObject.get("inner_key2").toString())
.addTextBody("inner_key3", jsonObject.get("inner_key3").toString())
.addBinaryBody("image", new File(imagePath))
.build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Apache's `MultipartEntityBuilder`.

But you could always send your image as a [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) field in your json object. In the server, you'd need to map that to a `byte[]` field.

Comment: This is a nice suggestion, but I'm trying to avoid it because of overhead, potential out of memory errors, and extra work on the server-side.